# What is the time complexity of the following python codes

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity

```
def lcs(X,Y,i,j):
  if (i == 0 or j == 0):
    return 0
  elif X[i-1] == Y[j-1]:
    return 1 + lcs(X,Y,i-1,j-1)
  else:
    return max(lcs(X,Y,i,j-1),lcs(X,Y,i-1,j))
```

---

```
def lcs(X,Y,i,j):
  if c[i][j] >= 0:
    return c[i][j]
  if (i == 0 or j == 0):
    c[i][j] = 0
  elif X[i-1] == Y[j-1]:
    c[i][j] = 1 + lcs(X,Y,i-1,j-1)
  else:
    c[i][j] = max(lcs(X,Y,i,j-1),lcs(X,Y,i-1,j))
  return c[i][j]
```

---

Second one works faster than first. But i found their time complexities the same as O(N2).

Comment: The second one crashes on my machine, because there is no variable named `c`.

Comment: One n^2 algorithm can be 1000 faster compared to another n^2 algorithm, they still have the same complexity.

Comment: Actually the first function's complexity is exponential. Every recursive call makes 2 new recursive calls. A lot of values are calculated more than once. This is a classic "pitfall", often encountered for instance when writing code for the Fibonacci function.

Comment: An O(n^2) algorithm can be 1000x faster than another O(n) algorithm, depending on the particular size of `n`. Time complexity is not about how fast a particular algorithm is, but how it *scales* as input size increases.

Comment: The second function is a "memoized" version of the first function. All the calculated values are stored in array `c`, to avoid recalculating them. Thus, the double recursive call `max(lcs(X,Y,i,j-1),lcs(X,Y,i-1,j))` doesn't blow up the number of recursive calls, because most recursive calls terminate immediately with "oh, this value has already been calculated, it's in the table"

Comment: thanks for all your comments. I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the first function is exponential. Every recursive call makes 2 new recursive calls. A lot of values are calculated more than once. This is a classic "pitfall", often encountered for instance when writing code for the Fibonacci function.

The second function is a "memoized" version of the first function. All the calculated values are stored in table `c`, to avoid recalculating them. Thus, the double recursive call `max(lcs(X,Y,i,j-1),lcs(X,Y,i-1,j))` doesn't blow up the number of recursive calls, because most recursive calls terminate immediately with "oh, this value has already been calculated, it's in the table".